# JSON serialization for Passwords when Testing

Tags: java, json, spring

I am currently writing a REST controller intended for handling user profiles/activity using Spring Boot.
For production, I currently have user's passwords hidden in the response using:

```java
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
```

However, when I am writing integration tests and making http requests to the controller, I would like to serialize my user object, but include the password so I can test functionality such as registering a new user. This is done using:

```java
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
...
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

Is there a test annotation that I could use or is there another serialization method available that will ignore the @JsonProperty annotation and allow the password to be serialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any way that you can do that. The only possible thing I can think of is to have an `interface` with 2 Profile classes implementing it, one without that `JsonProperty` and one with. Switch them using `@Profile` annotation

If serialization is not mandatory then you can still do your assertions using values from `getter`. If serialization is mandatory then I can only think of the alternative above.